# Excel VBA Cell Auto Advance Sub Splitting Words

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a VBA sub routine in an Excel sheet that prompts the user with an input box, inserts the data into a cell, and automatically advances to the cell below if the entire string will not fit into a single cell.  It works, but the code will advance to the next line even if it has to split a word to do it.  I do not want this, and I would appreciate some suggestions on how to improve my code so that Excel not only advances cells, but advances cells with words that don't get cut off.

```
Sub AutoCellAdvance()

If bolEditMode = True Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim str As String, x As Integer, y As Integer

intPlaceholder = Sheet1.Range("AE1").Value

If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
    str = InputBox("Enter Description of Activities (Max 192 characters)", "Incidents, Messages, Orders, Etc.")
    y = 0
    For x = 1 To Len(str) Step 64
        ActiveCell.Offset(y, 0) = "" & Mid(str, x, 64)
        If Len(str) > 64 And Len(str) <= 128 And intPlaceholder = 6 Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, -4).Resize(1, 4).Value = Chr(151) & Chr(151)
        End If
        If Len(str) > 128 And Len(str) < 192 And intPlaceholder = 6 Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, -4).Resize(2, 4).Value = Chr(151) & Chr(151)
        End If
        If Len(str) >= 192 And intPlaceholder = 6 Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, -4).Resize(3, 4).Value = Chr(151) & Chr(151)
        End If
        y = y + 1
    Next

Else
Exit Sub
End If

End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal target As Range)

'Incident, Messages, Orders, Etc. Input
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Intersect(target, Range("N12,N13,N14,N15,N16,N17,N18,N19,N20,N21,N22,N23,N24,N25,N26,N27,N28,N29,N30,N31,N32,N33,N34,N35,N36,N37,N38,N39,N40,N41,N42,N43,N44"))
If rng Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
ElseIf target.Count > 14 Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    Dim cl As Range
    For Each cl In rng
        AutoCellAdvance
    Next cl
End If

Selection.Font.Name = "arial"
Selection.Font.Size = 10

End Sub
```

Comment: Code is now up, but please pardon line break issues.  I am posting from my iPhone.

Comment: Could be a single word in `str` greater than 64 character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. The code below splits the input string, into an array of strings based on the delimiter " ". It then loops through the string array. Whenever it reaches a size of 64 it goes to the next line.

```
Sub AutoCellAdvance()

Dim strTemp As String
Dim arrStrings() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim strNew As String

Range("A1").Activate

strTemp = InputBox("Enter Description of Activities (Max 192 characters)", "Incidents, Messages, Orders, Etc.")
'splits the string based on the delimeter space
arrStrings = Split(strTemp, " ")
strNew = ""
'loops through the strings
For i = LBound(arrStrings) To UBound(arrStrings)
    If Len(strNew + arrStrings(i)) < 64 Then
        'as long as its smaller than 64 its adds the string to the rest of the strings
        strNew = strNew + arrStrings(i) + " "
    Else
        'if its larger than 64 then it prints the value in the active cell and goes down a row
        ActiveCell = strNew
        strNew = arrStrings(i)
        Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, ActiveCell.Column), Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, ActiveCell.Column)).Activate
    End If

Next i
ActiveCell = strNew

End Sub
```

Also here's an article I've written about string processing on my blog. It also talks about splitting strings. [String Processing](http://software-solutions-online.com/2014/02/11/2/)

Comment: Thank you for your response!  Do I replace the For Next loop that currently exists with this one?

Comment: No problem. Yes, . You should replace the for  next loop with the one i've written. Note that arrstrings is not a string like the one in your code, but an array of strings split based on the " " delimeter

Comment: I can't replace the code, because the For a Next loop I currently have established inserts a placeholder symbol in two smaller cells that contain time values if the value of the input box is larger than 64 characters.  Rather, I need a way to use both.